# The React Context Keeps Displaying the Previous State Values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, react-context

I am building an app where you can multiple stores, all the stores are displayed on a stores page, when you click on a store you get its details and its items, the problem i am facing is that when i click on lets say mcdonalds the first time it works fine , then i go back and click on another store for ex kfc it shows me the details of the previous store mcdonalds

this is the displayItems component where it shows the items and the store details
`` ` ``

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import CameraIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PhotoCamera";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardActions from "@mui/material/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@mui/material/CardMedia";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import AddItemModal from "../../AddItemModal/AddItemModal";
import { ItemContext } from "../../context/items.context";
import { StoreContext } from "../../context/stores.context";

const defaultTheme = createTheme();

const DisplayItems = () => {
  const { getItems, items } = useContext(ItemContext);

  const {
    setCurrentStore,
    currentStore,
    getCurrentStoreDetails,
    currentStoreDetails,
  } = useContext(StoreContext);

  const { storeid } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentStore(storeid);
  }, [storeid]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentStore) {
      getItems();
      getCurrentStoreDetails();
    }
  }, [currentStore]);

  console.log("the current store is", currentStore);
  console.log("the current items are ", items);
  console.log("the current store details are ", currentStoreDetails);

  const { storeName, storeDesc } = currentStoreDetails;
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="relative">
        <Toolbar>
          <CameraIcon sx={{ mr: 2 }} />
          <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
            {storeName}
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <main>
        {/* Hero unit */}
        <Box
          sx={{
            bgcolor: "background.paper",
            pt: 8,
            pb: 6,
          }}
        >
          <Container maxWidth="sm">
            <Typography
              component="h1"
              variant="h2"
              align="center"
              color="text.primary"
              gutterBottom
            >
              {storeName}
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              variant="h5"
              align="center"
              color="text.secondary"
              paragraph
            >
              {storeDesc}
            </Typography>
            <Stack
              sx={{ pt: 4 }}
              direction="row"
              spacing={2}
              justifyContent="center"
            >
              <AddItemModal />
            </Stack>
          </Container>
        </Box>
        <Container sx={{ py: 8 }} maxWidth="md">
          {/* End hero unit */}
          <Grid container spacing={4}>
            {Array.isArray(items) && items.length > 0 ? (
              items.map((item) => (
                <Grid item key={item._id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                  <Card
                    sx={{
                      height: "100%",
                      display: "flex",
                      flexDirection: "column",
                      transition: "transform 0.2s ease",
                      "&:hover": {
                        transform: "scale(1.05)",
                      },
                    }}
                    variant="outlined"
                  >
                    <CardMedia
                      component="div"
                      sx={{
                        pt: "56.25%",
                      }}
                      image={`${item.itemPic}`}
                    />
                    <CardContent sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                      <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                        {item.itemName}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography align="center" variant="h6">
                        Price : {item.itemPrice}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography align="center" variant="h6">
                        {item.itemDesc}
                      </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                    <CardActions>
                      <Button size="small">View</Button>
                      <Button size="small">Edit</Button>
                    </CardActions>
                  </Card>
                </Grid>
              ))
            ) : (
              <Typography variant="h6">No items available.</Typography>
            )}
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </main>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default DisplayItems;
```

this is the storesPreview where all the store are displayed

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardActions from "@mui/material/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@mui/material/CardMedia";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import AddStoreModal from "../AddStoreModal/AddStoreModal";
import { StoreContext } from "../../context/stores.context";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const defaultTheme = createTheme();

const StoresPreview = () => {
  const { getStores, stores, setCurrentStoreDetails } =
    useContext(StoreContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    getStores();
    setCurrentStoreDetails({});
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
        <CssBaseline />

        <main>
          {/* Hero unit */}
          <Box
            sx={{
              bgcolor: "background.paper",
              pt: 8,
              pb: 6,
            }}
          >
            <Container maxWidth="sm">
              <Typography
                component="h1"
                variant="h2"
                align="center"
                color="text.primary"
                gutterBottom
              >
                Stores
              </Typography>
              <Stack
                sx={{ pt: 4 }}
                direction="row"
                spacing={2}
                justifyContent="center"
              >
                <AddStoreModal />
              </Stack>
            </Container>
          </Box>
          <Container sx={{ py: 8 }} maxWidth="md">
            {/* End hero unit */}
            <Grid container spacing={4}>
              {stores.map((store) => (
                <Grid item key={store._id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                  <Card
                    sx={{
                      height: "100%",
                      display: "flex",
                      flexDirection: "column",
                      transition: "transform 0.2s ease",
                      "&:hover": {
                        transform: "scale(1.05)",
                      },
                    }}
                    variant="outlined"
                  >
                    <Link
                      to={`/stores/${store._id}`}
                      style={{
                        textDecoration: "none",
                        color: "inherit",
                        cursor: "pointer",
                      }}
                    >
                      <CardMedia
                        component="div"
                        sx={{
                          // 16:9
                          pt: "56.25%",
                        }}
                        image={`${store.storePic}`}
                      />
                      <CardContent sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                          {store.storeName}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography>{store.storeDesc}</Typography>
                      </CardContent>
                    </Link>
                    <CardActions>
                      <Button size="small">View</Button>
                      <Button size="small">Edit</Button>
                    </CardActions>
                  </Card>
                </Grid>
              ))}
            </Grid>
          </Container>
        </main>
        {/* Footer */}
        <Box
          sx={{ bgcolor: "background.paper", p: 6 }}
          component="footer"
        ></Box>
        {/* End footer */}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default StoresPreview;
```

```
import { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { StoreContext } from "./stores.context";

const host = "http://localhost:5000";

export const ItemContext = createContext({
  items: [],
  setItems: () => null,
});

export const ItemProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const { currentStore } = useContext(StoreContext);

  //ADD ITEMS
  const addItem = async (
    itemStoreID,
    itemName,
    itemDesc,
    itemPic,
    itemPrice
  ) => {
    // TODO: API Call
    // API Call
    const apiUrl = `${host}/api/item/additem`;

    const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        itemStoreID,
        itemName,
        itemDesc,
        itemPic,
        itemPrice,
      }),
    });

    const item = await response.json();
    console.log(item);
    setItems(items.concat(item));
  };

  // GET ITEMS FOR THE SPECIFIC STORE
  const getItems = async (itemStoreID) => {
    // API Call
    const apiUrl = `${host}/api/item/${currentStore}`;

    const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    const itemsMap = await response.json();
    console.log(itemsMap);
    setItems(itemsMap);
  };

  const value = {
    items,
    setItems,
    addItem,
    getItems,
  };

  return <ItemContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</ItemContext.Provider>;
};
```

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { useState, createContext } from "react";
import { AdminContext } from "./admin.context";

const host = "http://localhost:5000";

export const StoreContext = createContext({
  stores: [],
  setStores: () => null,
  currentStore: null,
  setCurrentStore: () => null,
  currentStoreDetails: {},
  setCurrentStoreDetails: () => null,
});

export const StoreProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [stores, setStores] = useState([]);
  const [currentStore, setCurrentStore] = useState(null);
  const [currentStoreDetails, setCurrentStoreDetails] = useState({});
  const { currentAdmin } = useContext(AdminContext);

  //ADD A STORE

  // Add a Note
  const addStore = async (storeName, storeDesc, storePic, storeLocation) => {
    // TODO: API Call
    // API Call
    const apiUrl = `${host}/api/stores/addstore`;

    const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "auth-token": currentAdmin,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ storeName, storeDesc, storePic, storeLocation }),
    });

    const store = await response.json();
    console.log(store);
    setStores(stores.concat(store));
  };

  const getStores = async () => {
    // API Call
    const apiUrl = `${host}/api/stores/getstores`;

    const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "auth-token": currentAdmin,
      },
    });

    const stores = await response.json();
    console.log(stores);
    setStores(stores);
  };
  // get current store details

  const getCurrentStoreDetails = async () => {
    // API Call
    const apiUrl = `${host}/api/stores/${currentStore}`;

    const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    const storeDetails = await response.json();
    console.log(storeDetails);
    setCurrentStoreDetails(storeDetails);
  };

  const value = {
    stores,
    setStores,
    currentStore,
    setCurrentStore,
    currentStoreDetails,
    setCurrentStoreDetails,
    addStore,
    getStores,
    getCurrentStoreDetails,
  };

  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</StoreContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

i think its the problem with the use of useEffects but i cant seem it to get it setup correctly
PS: i am using mongodb and express as the backend